# How to pass variables to a google_storage_bucket_object in terraform 13.5

Tags: google-cloud-storage, terraform, interpolation

I have a google storage bucket object that gets created (via terraform)like so:

```
resource "google_storage_bucket_object" "my_post_startup_script" {
  name   = "my-script.sh"
  source = "${path.module}/my-script.sh"
  bucket = my_bucket
}
```

But inside that script are things I'd like to make variables.

So say my-script.sh looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "hello ${name}"
```

Is there a way for me to pass a variable in so to be interpolated so that the script that gets uploaded actually says "hello John"

This may requires some intermediate step that creates a file with the variable interpolation that I can then pass in as the source for the google_storage_bucket_object - but not sure how that would be done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the way you've written this so far, it's the Google provider itself that reads the file `my-script.sh`, and so by that time it's too late for any further Terraform template processing; template processing is part of the Terraform language itself and happens before passing the configuration to the provider.

However, [`google_storage_bucket_object`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/storage_bucket_object) also has an alternative argument `content` which allows you to pass the desired content directly to the provider, without the provider needing to read it from a file itself. In its simplest form that allows you to send constant values into the provider without writing them to disk first:

```
resource "google_storage_bucket_object" "my_post_startup_script" {
  name   = "my-script.sh"
  bucket = my_bucket

  content = "Hello world!"
}
```

However, that `content` argument can take any valid Terraform language expression which returns a string, and one such example is a call to [`templatefile`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/templatefile.html), which is a function that asks Terraform itself (the core runtime, not the provider) to read a file from disk and interpret its content as a [string template](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/strings.html#string-templates).

Putting those two things together, you can do this:

```
resource "google_storage_bucket_object" "my_post_startup_script" {
  name   = "my-script.sh"
  bucket = my_bucket

  content = templatefile("${path.module}/my-script.sh", {
    name = var.example_name
  })
}
```

For the simple example you've shared here, it doesn't make a great deal of difference whether it's Terraform itself or the Google Cloud Platform provider that ultimately reads the file from disk, but there are some practical differences that might be important in other situations:

- Terraform strings are always sequences of Unicode characters rather than raw bytes, and so passing a value using `content` requires that the content be a Unicode string, and the provider will encode it as UTF-8 before saving it. If you use `source`, on the other hand, the provider will just take the raw bytes in the file exactly as-is and upload them, and so you can potentially upload text in other character encodings or upload files that aren't text at all.
- Because it's now the string resulting from rendering the template being sent to the provider, rather than just a filename, you'll see the content itself shown in the Terraform plan output with `content`, whereas with `source` you would previously have seen just the filename. In many cases folks consider this to be an *advantage* of using `content` rather than a disadvantage, but it could be troublesome if the content is particularly large (thus making the plan output long) or if it contains content that isn't appropriate to show in the console output.
- There are practical limits on how large a Terraform resource configuration can be, resulting from various technical details such as the provider protocol, the SDK, and the memory available on your system, and so using `content` is appropriate only for relatively small objects, such as scripts and other small configuration files.

---

If your use-case includes processing a large number of template files gathered together in a subdirectory, you might find [the Terraform module `hashicorp/dir/template`](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/hashicorp/dir/template/latest) useful. It wraps both `templatefile` and `fileset` function calls to prepare a number of files for uploading all at once, returning them in a way that [you can pass conveniently to a `google_storage_bucket_object` resource using `for_each`](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/hashicorp/dir/template/latest#uploading-files-to-google-cloud-storage).

Comment: Excellent answer and explanation of how `content` works.